# Save window of controls with runtime geneated controls and reload with as previous state

Tags: c#, wpf, runtime, save

I created project with thee control buttons. AddButton creates runtime button controls and adds it in canvas1. When i right click on runtime generated controls new window pop ups. I want to save this window and reload it with same state as i leave. I use xml serialisation, it loads but click on that buttons does't work.

Here is my code:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

                Button b = new Button();
                b.MinHeight = 23;
                b.MinWidth = 73;             
                b.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.GetPosition(this).X);
                b.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.GetPosition(this).Y);
                b.Content = i.ToString();          
                canvas1.Children.Add(b);      
                b.MouseRightButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(NewButton_Click);

}

 private void NewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;

            ContextMenu pMenu = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem();
            item1.Header = "Properties";           
            pMenu.Items.Add(item1);
            btn.ContextMenu = pMenu;
            item1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(item1_Click);
        }


 private void item1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem btn = (MenuItem)sender;
         ControlProp c = new ControlProp();
         c.ShowDialog();  

        }     

  private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder outstr = new StringBuilder();

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;


            XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm = new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(outstr, settings));
            dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;

            XamlWriter.Save(this.canvas1, dsm);
            string savedControls = outstr.ToString();

            //Show Dialog Box
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xaml"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "Xaml documents (.xaml)|*.xaml"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show save file dialog box
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Process save file dialog box results
            if (result == true)
            {
                // Save document
                string filename = dlg.FileName;
                File.WriteAllText(filename, savedControls);
            }

        }

        private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Open FileDialog
            string filename;
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xaml"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "Xaml documents (.xaml)|*.xaml"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show save file dialog box
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Process save file dialog box results
            if (result == true)
            {
                // Save document
                 filename = dlg.FileName;

                //Open Xaml
                 StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(filename);
                 string text = sR.ReadToEnd();
                 sR.Close();

                 StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text);
                 XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

                 Canvas wp = (Canvas)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

                 canvas1.Children.Clear(); // clear the existing children

                 foreach (FrameworkElement child in wp.Children) // and for each child in the WrapPanel we just loaded (wp)
                 {
                     canvas1.Children.Add(CloneFrameworkElement(child)); // clone the child and add it to our existing wrap panel
                 }      
            }


        }

        FrameworkElement CloneFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement originalElement)
        {
            string elementString = XamlWriter.Save(originalElement);

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(elementString);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            FrameworkElement clonedElement = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

            return clonedElement;
        }
```

In short ,i want to save my project that user created at runtime and reopen it like mspaint with save project and open project facility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XamlWriter ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx))